# timeIntervalSinceDate reporting wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I've got two dates that are set with a button press. These are stored in a custom object that inherits from NSObject.

**Properties:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *firstDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *secondDate;
```

**Custom getter and setter methods:**

```
- (void)setFirstDate:(float)firstDate {
    _firstDate = [self dateByOmittingSeconds:firstDate];
}

- (void)setSecondDate:(float)secondDate {
    _secondDate = [self dateByOmittingSeconds:secondDate];
}

- (NSDate *)firstDate {
    return [self dateByOmittingSeconds:_firstDate];
}

- (NSDate *)secondDate {
    return [self dateByOmittingSeconds:_secondDate];
}
```

**Function that removes the seconds part of the NSDate:**

```
-(NSDate *)dateByOmittingSeconds:(NSDate *)date
{
// Setup an NSCalendar
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

// Setup NSDateComponents
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date];

// Set the seconds
[components setSecond:00];

return [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents: components];
}
```

firstDate is **08:00** and secondDate is **13:00**, both are set today.

**I'm getting the distance between the two dates and format them like this:**

```
NSString *myString = [self timeFormatted:[currentModel.secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentModel.firstDate]];


- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)totalSeconds
{

// int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%luh %lum", (unsigned long)hours, (unsigned long)minutes];
}
```

But it reports **4h 59m**, **17999.254732 seconds**.

Does anyone have a clue on why this is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not `timeIntervalSinceDate` but your 
 `dateByOmittingSeconds` method which does not correctly truncate
to seconds. The reason is that `second` is not the smallest unit in `NSDateComponents`.
There is also `nanosecond` and if you set that one to zero as well

```
[components setSecond:0];
[components setNanosecond:0];
```

then it will work as expected.

A slightly easier solution is to use `rangeOfUnit`:

```
-(NSDate *)dateByOmittingSeconds:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDate *result;
    [gregorianCalendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitSecond startDate:&result interval:nil forDate:date];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I came up with that idea myself that there might have been a smaller unit and tried to find like setMillisecond or similar but I couldn't find it. Nanosecond is the unit I was looking for - works perfectly now, thanks a lot!